# Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, it is possible to cover $\textbf{Q}$ by a countable number of intervals whose total length is less than $\varepsilon$.

Tags: solution-verification, rational-numbers, outer-measure

The book which I am reading says

> One consequence of the fact that $m^{*}(\textbf{Q}) = 0$ is that given any $\varepsilon > 0$, it is possible to cover the rationals $\textbf{Q}$ by a countable number of intervals whose total length is less than $\varepsilon$.

After some thought, I came up with the following solution. Since $|\textbf{Q}| = |\textbf{N}|$, we can count the rationals as we count the the naturals. More precise, for each rational number $q_{i}$ we can consider the interval $I_{i} = (q_{i} - \varepsilon/2^{i+2},q_{i} + \varepsilon/2^{i+2})$ which contains $q_{i}$. Consequently, we have that
\begin{align*}
\textbf{Q} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\{q_{i}\}\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(q_{i}-\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{i+2}},q_{i} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{i+2}}\right)
\end{align*}

Since $|I_{i}| = 2^{-i-1}\varepsilon$, the total length of such intervals equals

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|I_{i}| = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^{-i-1}\varepsilon = \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Is it correctly thought? Am I missing something? Is there another way to prove the proposed statement?

Comment: From my view your proof is correct.

Comment: It is not correct. You should consider $(q_i-\varepsilon/2^{i+2},q_i+\varepsilon/2^{i+2})$ instead of $(-\varepsilon/2^{i+2},\varepsilon/2^{i+2})$

Comment: I thought that the heart of this argument is actually the typical *proof* that $m^*(\mathbb{Q})=0$, so I wonder what their proof was?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That should be an answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the comment! I have fixed it.

Comment: @AlexR. in order to prove that $m^{*}(\textbf{Q}) = 0$, he has used the countable sub-additivity property of the outer measure as well as the fact that $m^{*}(\{q_{i}\}) = 0$ and $m^{*}(\Omega)\geq 0$.